# Multiply outputs from two Conv2D layers in TensorFlow 2+

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I’m trying to implement SOLO architecture for instance segmentation in TensorFlow (Decoupled version).

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.04488.pdf

Right now, I need to compute the loss function and multiply each output map from first conv2d layer with output maps of second layer.

```
xi = Conv2D(…)(input) # output is (batch, None, None, 24)
yi = Conv2D(…)(input) # output is (batch, None, None, 24)
```

I need to multiply each output maps (element wise) `xi` with `yi` in a way to get output with `(batch, None, None, 24*24)`. I need element-wise multiplication of one output feature map (from first conv2d) with all from second conv2d layer and so on. **Thats why 24 * 24**.

I try to do this with for cycles but get error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over tf.Tensor is not allowed: 
                                                    AutoGraph did convert this function.
```

Any advice to achieve this with some TF2 operation?

Comment: How did you try this? Add what you have done so far.

Comment: results = []
for x in xi:
  for y in yi:
     results.append(tf.multiply(x,y))

Comment: I don't know what is the best solution, but I think if you pass run eagerly to model compile, like this `model.compile(...,run_eagerly=True)` may remove the error.

Comment: Id does not :(, using tensorflow 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically the outer product of the last dimension followed by collapsing the last 2 dimensions. A short way to express this operation is to use `tf.repeat` and `tf.tile`.

```
#channel_dims is the length of the last dimension, i.e. 24 in your question 
@tf.function
def outerprodflatten(x,y,channel_dims):
  return tf.repeat(x,channel_dims,-1)*tf.tile(y,[1,1,1,channel_dims])
```

To use this in functional API, you would also have to define a custom keras layer or lambda layer, i.e.

```
class Outerprodflatten_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, channel_dims):
        self.channel_dims = channel_dims
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.repeat(inputs[0],self.channel_dims,-1)*tf.tile(inputs[1],[1,1,1,self.channel_dims])

x = Conv2D(…)(input) # output is (batch, None, None, 24)
y = Conv2D(…)(input) # output is (batch, None, None, 24)

out=Outerprodflatten_layer(24)([x,y])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Multiply` layer to do this

```
multiplied = tensorflow.keras.layers.Multiply()([xi,yi])
```

This layer multiplies (element-wise) a list of inputs.
It takes as input a list of tensors, all of the same shape, and returns a single tensor (also of the same shape).

Comment: Thank you but already tried this. In this way I get output (batch, None, None, 24) and not (batch, None, None, 24*24). I need elementwise multiplication of each conv output with each conv output and not output of the same shape.

Comment: How can an element-wise multiplication result from (batch, None, None, 24) to (batch, None, None, 24*24)? Element-wise multiplications can only be carried out on matrices of same shapes and the output is also that same shape, the values are just changed, not the shape

Comment: I need element-wise multiplication of one output feature map (from first conv2d) with all from second conv2d layer and so on. Thats why 24 * 24.